# C# Switch Randomized

Tags: c#, random, switch-statement, case

I have code, there is variable and switch, and switch result is always variable value, that's ok, but, can the result random? Thanks.

Code: http://pastebin.com/5zuiVCtY

Comment: Don't link to pastebin, add the relevant code in your post.

Comment: I couldn't. Much code, less text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I get it correctly, but you may try

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int caseSwitch = rnd.Next(1, 13);
```

Comment: @user3592727 watch out though to not call the new Random() in a loop otherwise you probably will get identical values.

Comment: @user3592727 welcome. This issues is trivial, so, next time please try to find solution in documentation or search for it in web before asking a question here.